# getting error on fcm 'Authorization: key='.FIREBASE_API_KEY

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Actually I am working on firebase cloud messaging.then
when I.send the notification through index.php I'm getting Error on firebase.php 42 line
the line of code is 'Authorization: key='.FIREBASE_API_KEY, Please Anyone Solve my Problem[open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1gyO.png)

Error Line:-
Notice: Use of undefined constant FIREBASE_API_KEY - assumed 'FIREBASE_API_KEY' in firebase.php on line 42

Comment: Have you defined a constant variable for `FIREBASE_API_KEY`? First do that or replace that whole keyword with the actual firebase key you generated on the firebase console

Answer (score 0):

Use header as

"Authorization: Bearer token"

Refer doc for more

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: Because the OP is using [the legacy FCM server protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?authuser=0#send_messages_using_the_legacy_app_server_protocols), the authorization header contains `key=` instead of `Bearer`.